# x-www-form-urlencoded in Xamarin

Tags: c#, web-services, post, xamarin.android

I'm working on Xamarin.Android App. I have to consume rest API of content type x-www-form-urlencoded. I'm unable to call the Rest API Successfully, before this, I consumed many web services but I'm working on this type of API first time. I'm stuck in this. 
I tried two ways to consume it:

```
 public static string makePostEncodedRequest(string url, string jsonparams)
    {
        string ret = "";
        var httpwebrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpwebrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //httpwebrequest.Accept = Config.JsonHeaderAJ;
        httpwebrequest.Method = Methods.Post.ToString();

        byte[] bytearray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonparams);

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpwebrequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(bytearray);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpwebrequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            ret = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

the next one is:

```
   Dictionary<string, string> requestParams = new Dictionary<string, string ();

        requestParams.Add("value=", data1);
        requestParams.Add("&value=", data2);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(Config.DomainURl + Config.StudentLoginUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams)).Result;

            var tokne = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

Comment: `jsonparams` is either a misleading parameter name, or exactly the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used the following code for authenticating user in my project might help you.

```
public static async Task<UserData> GetUserAuth(UserAuth userauth)
    {
        bool asd= CheckNetWorkStatus().Result;
        if (asd)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(UrlAdd);// ("http://192.168.101.119:8475/");
            var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            var dto = new UserAuth { grant_type = userauth.grant_type, password = userauth.password, username = userauth.username };
            var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", userauth.grant_type));
            nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", userauth.password));
            nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userauth.username));
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, UrlAdd + "token") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) };

            var res = await client.SendAsync(req);
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(result);
                userData.ErrorMessage = "true";
                return userData;
            }
            else
            {
                UserData ud = new UserData();
                ud.ErrorMessage = "Incorrect Password";
                return ud;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UserData ud = new UserData();
            ud.ErrorMessage = "Check Ur Connectivity";
            return ud;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, could you please tell me about NativeMessageHandler. from which dll it can be used

Comment: @MohammedDastagir  have used modernhttpclient.2.4.2

Comment: @MohammedDastagir great to hear that , happy coding